# No me cargan los cambios de mi solución realizada en Blazor Wasm

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor, blazor

He estado trabajando con blazor de manera de práctica viendo un tutorial. Cuando agregué la nueva opción TO DOS y Le cambie los títulos a la vista todo funciono bien.

Ahora, cuando comencé a tocar un poco más la vista agregandole más funcionalidades, cuando vuelvo a cargar la vista , no me refleja los cambio.

Cabe destacar que el IDE no me refleja ni errores, ni warnings, hice el tutorial varias veces para leer letra por letra por si tengo errores , no los tengo, y no hallo la solución.

Probé borrando las carpetas Bin y OBJ pero no funciona.

Este es un fragmento del documento por defecto NavMenu.Razor que es donde le agrego la opcion To Dos a la vista

```
    <div class="nav-item px-3">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="todo">
            <span class="oi oi-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span> To Dos
        </NavLink>
    </div>
```

Mi doc Razor que creé:

```
`@page "/todo"`

>     <PageTitle>Mis To Dos</PageTitle>
>     <h1>To Dos Pendientes: (@toDos.Count(todo => !todo.EstaCompletado))</h1>

<table>
    <thead class= "py-5">
        <th class="col-lg-3">Completado?</th>
        <th class="col-lg-3">Titulo</th>
        <th class="col-lg-3">Contenido</th>
        <th class="col-lg-3">Fecha de Entrega</th>
    </thead>

    @foreach(var toDo in toDos)
    {
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" @bind="toDo.EstaCompletado"/></td>
            <td>@toDo.Titulo</td>
            <td>@toDo.Contenido</td>
            <td>@toDo.FechaEntrega</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

<h2>Añade Nuevos To Dos</h2>

<input placeholder="Añadir Titulo" @bind = "nuevoTitulo"/>
<input placeholder="Añadir Contenido" @bind="nuevoContenido" />
<button @onclick= AddToDo >Añadir To Do</button>

@code 
{
    private string? nuevoTitulo;
    private string? nuevoContenido;
    private List<ToDoItem> toDos = new(); 
    private void AddToDo()
    {
        // Añade el To Do
        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nuevoTitulo))
        {
            toDos.Add(new ToDoItem { 
                Titulo = nuevoTitulo, 
                Contenido = nuevoContenido , 
                FechaEntrega = new DateOnly(2022,1,31)
            });
            nuevoTitulo = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Mi clase que se usa para lo anterior:

```
public class ToDoItem
{
    public int TodoItemId { get; set; }

    public string? Titulo { get; set; }
    public string? Contenido { get; set; }
    public string? Responsable { get; set; }
    public List<string> Etiquetas { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    public DateOnly? FechaEntrega { get; set; }
    public TimeOnly? HoraEntrega { get; set; }
    public bool EstaCompletado { get; set; } = false;

}
```

El resultado errado es esta[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el documento App.razor que contiene ese error dejo la codificación por si es de ayuda.

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

Comment: Lectura recomendada antes que voten con negativos y/o te cierren la pregunta: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: Hablas del hot reload, o cuando volviendo a ejecutar la aplicación?

Comment: @Yussef exactamente , acabo de hacer una edición completa de la pregunta para que lo observes con mayor detalle. Pero si , al principio agregue cosas sencillas que si cambiar el título y agregar una nueva opción, lo compilé y se publicó sin problemas. Luego le agregué una clase nueva y más funcionalidades, compilé , se publicó pero no agarra el cambio, solo muestra ese mensaje.

Comment: `@page "/todo"` estas comillas invertidas están el código ???

Comment: @Yussef correcto está así en el código, esas comillas simples en la pregunta fué un error de tipeo mientras la redactaba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resuelto. No tengo la respuesta técnica , pero lo solucioné borrando el componente ToDo.razor y cree otro como Todo.razor.

El posible error fue que en pleno desarrollo , le cambie el nombre al .razor despues de haber compilado la solución bajo el nombre de Todo.razor , entonces asumo que a partir de aquí se generó el problema.

Recomendación: no cambies los nombres de tus archivos, después de haber realizado compilaciones.

De igual manera agradezco a los que participaron para ayudarme.

Nos veremos pronto ;).

Answer (score 0):

Si copio exactamente el codigo que colocas en la pagina *ToDo.razor* genera un error de compilacion por
[image: Error de compilacion por directiva @page]

Por eso seria bueno ver tu codigo completo, porque el error que mencionas en un error de ruteo.

Dejo [un ejemplo](https://github.com/fernandezja/blazor-experiments/tree/master/src) en un repo online si lo quieres descargar (lo subi para ver que la ruta este bien armada , lo puedes descargar y verificar)

- solamente subi este "cambio" hasta ahora[(el item del menu y la page)](https://github.com/fernandezja/blazor-experiments/commit/ae3826566b5ac0b124b7b37cac9db9b96e13d949)
- El proyecto Starwars.App.Wasm.sln > https://github.com/fernandezja/blazor-experiments/tree/master/src

[image: ejemplo de solucion de Blazore Webassembly]

y la ruta a la pagina funcionando
[image: Ejemplo de ruta de todo]

Tambien actualice para que pueda funcionar, solo la modificacion fue en el codigo que enviaste aqui

```
<button @onclick= AddToDo >Añadir To Do</button>
```

por

```
<button @onclick="AddToDo">Añadir To Do</button>
```

Ademas de colocar la clase ToDoItem dentro de una carpeta "Entities" (ademas importe el namespaces en _Imports.razor)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guia

Comment: Jose muchas gracias por tu respuesta, ahora te explico, las comillas se colocaron por error al momento de estar redactando la pregunta.  El error es correcto es por ruteo. Con respecto al código, si tienes tiempo puedes agregarle al proyecto la clase ToDoItem, exactamente como sale en la pregunta e intenta generarlo de nuevo, colocandole la clase tendrás exactamente el mismo proyecto que tengo yo.

De igual manera, voy a leer el código que me facilitaste, volveré a probar y te notifico.

Considero yo que el problema es por el Caché o algo relacionado.

Comment: @AnthonySanchez agregue la clase ToDoItem, dentro de una carpeta "Entities" (ademas importe el namespaces en _Imports.razor). solo tuve que modificar, el codigo del Button submit poque no tiene que tener espacio en el atributo onclick. [Este es el commit](https://github.com/fernandezja/blazor-experiments/commit/b4ba3ab890870736c4d64ee3d471c9c2b58ad37c)